# DelayedJob + Rails 4 + rake jobs:work => undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I just upgraded to Rails 4 and my jobs are not starting. When I run `bundle exec rake jobs:work --trace` I got `undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass` and this [stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/nim1989/6987976) ...

I don't know where to start looking for this error. Any ideas?

I'm using Rails 4.0.0 and delayed_job_active_record 4.0.0. Here is my [Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/nim1989/6987998) if it can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the value of array is nil so first put raise in rake file and check the value of that array.

Comment: It looks like you are probably using the protected_attributes gem. That must come before DJ in your Gemfile.

Comment: @hypee On a new project, adding the `protected_attributes` gem before delayed_job, fixes the problem, but not in my case, so it must be another gem I think. I have to figure this out.

Comment: Seems the handler is not in way waiting by delayed_job ( `/\!ruby\/\w+\:([^\s]+)/` )

Comment: comment this lines in your gem `https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/v4.0.0/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb#L79:L80` to see the handler, you get

Comment: If I comment this line my jobs are being processed... If I replace the line with `puts handler`, a blank line get put.

Comment: If I just add unless handler.bank? at the end of the line, it fixes the problem... So I forked the project and linked the gem to https://github.com/nim1989/delayed_job Maybe I should open an issue there and make a PR to delayed_job.

Comment: Actually, a new project with the exact same gemfile doesn't trigger the error, so it comes from somewhere else...!

Comment: Okay, it just works now. I think the problem just come from the fact that I had Jobs without handlers...